# Plotting Hermite-Gaussian polynomial for Gaussian beams

Tags: plotting, special-functions, physics

Can you show me all the steps and the code to trace the Hermite modes with *Mathematica* 11?

[image: plots]

I want to draw the Hermite Gauss mode for a Gaussian beam with *Mathematica* 11 but I can not write a program.

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck? Have a look at [DensityPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html) and [HermiteH](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HermiteH.html)

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Plotting Hermite-Gaussian polynomial for Gaussian beams

Comment: This is how PhDs are made nowadays...

Comment: No but mathematica is new software I have ever used

Comment: I do not know how to draw Plotting Hermite-Gaussian polynomial in 2D and 3D and I do not find on the internet how to do

Answer (score 8):

First define a function that describes the intensity as a function of both $x$ and $y$ position for each $\mathrm{TEM}_\mathrm{mn}$ mode (see wiki on [laser modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_mode#Laser_modes)):

```
Imn[x_, y_, m_, n_] := (HermiteH[m, x] Exp[-x^2/2])^2 (HermiteH[n, y] Exp[-y^2/2])^2
```

Then use [`DensityPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html) to plot this function across the $x,y$ plane - I make use of `Epilog` to add the text labels. This is all done from within `Table` to plot for several $m,n$. Finally I wrap that in `TableForm` for the output formatting.

```
opts = Sequence[PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, Frame -> False, PlotRangePadding -> None];

TableForm[
 Table[
  DensityPlot[Imn[x, y, m, n], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Evaluate@opts,
   Epilog -> Text[Style[StringJoin[ToString /@ {m, n}], 24, White], Scaled[{0.5, 0.1}]]
   ],
  {n, 0, 3}, {m, 0, 3}
  ],
 TableSpacing -> {0, 0}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: An equivalent expression, which may be more familiar for some, is `Imn[x_, y_, m_, n_] := 2^(m + n) (ParabolicCylinderD[m, Sqrt[2] x] ParabolicCylinderD[n, Sqrt[2] y])^2`.

Comment: Your program does not work I can not reproduce the image, is what you can tell me how to write the program on mathematica etape by step

Comment: Copy the code above and run it... There's really nothing more to it! You'll have to be more specific than "Your program does not work" for more useful advice...

Comment: please Is that you can write me the program correctly so that I can copy the paste directly on mathematica because it is an execice that must do and I can not do it alone

Comment: @user47849 works out of hand in V11. Restart mathematica, copy both code blocks and evaluate them.

Comment: Thank you very much it works, I still need the same drawing but in 2D and 3D is what you can show me how to trace

Comment: @user47849 Very nice answer, however, do not expect a free thesis writing service here

Comment: No but mathematica is new software I have ever used ,This is an exercise that the teacher asked us for exercises us using mathematica and advised us to search and ask questions on the internet

Comment: I do not know how to draw Plotting Hermite-Gaussian polynomial in 2D and 3D and I do not find on the internet how to do